# Is it possible to extract youtube video metrics without being a channel owner or content owner?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api

I have read the documentation on [YouTube - Analytics and Reporting APIs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/) and I am able to extract analytics data being a channel owner or content owner. Is there an API to extract metrics about a video which I do not own in Youtube?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Youtube metrics requires authorization so I don't think that's entirely possible. But, if you just want to query about a random video's `viewCount`, `likeCount`, `dislikeCount`, `favoriteCount`, and `commentCount`, you can use [videos.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) and provide statistics as the part parameter.

Comment: Tried the API in explorer. This helps. Thanks.